# Is it Possible to Query Import Range Off Another Query Important?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that is using Query Import Range to bring in data from another sheet and I have built another sheet off that data. Now I am trying to create 66 different spreadsheets (different schools) using Query Import Range but it's only pulling up to the columns that were originally imported. Can someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output